# Managerial Economics

Tags: probability

1. A salesman is known to sell a product in 3 out of 5 attempts. While another salesman in 2 out of 5 attempts. Find the probability that
   a.  No sales will happen
   b.  Either of them will succeed in selling the product

Comment: Please don't use all caps, what have you tried ?

Comment: Do we assume they each make $5$ attempts?  The answers you have gotten do so, but the question doesn't say.

Answer (score 3):

The probability that both will succeed is $\left(\frac35\right)\left(\frac25\right)=\frac6{25}$

The probability that no sales will happen is $\left(1-\frac35\right)\left(1-\frac25\right)=\frac6{25}$

The probability that at least one will succeed is $1-\left(1-\frac35\right)\left(1-\frac25\right)=\frac{19}{25}$

Answer (score 0):

Let the probability of event A be P(A)=3/5, and event B be P(B)=2/5. Since these are not mutually exclusive, the probability of success is simply equal to P(A)P(B).  Use q=1-p for both the find the probability of no success, i.e. Q(A)Q(B).